# Problem with \foreach in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm using \foreach in Tikz to make a line with vertical marks at some real numbers. But I want to put \pi and \e (Euler number) in the code, but it doesnt work. Please, can anyone help me?

My Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
\draw [->] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
\foreach \x in  {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in  {1/2,4/3,-2/3}
\draw[shift={(\y,0)},color=black] (0pt,-3pt) -- (0pt,3pt) node[above] {$\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

I want:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
\draw [->] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
\foreach \x in  {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in  {1/2,4/3,-2/3, \pi, \e}
\draw[shift={(\y,0)},color=black] (0pt,-3pt) -- (0pt,3pt) node[above] {$\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put the fragments into a complete compilable (even with error) document.  In your second example, you should use `e` and `pi` not `\e` and `\pi`.

Comment: Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-stealth] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
\foreach \X in  {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
{\draw (\X,3pt) -- (\X,-3pt) node[below] {$\X$};}
\foreach \Y/\Z in  {1/2/\frac{1}{2},4/3/\frac{4}{3},-2/3/\frac{-2}{3}, pi/\pi,
e/\mathrm{e}}
{\draw (\Y,-3pt) -- (\Y,3pt) node[above] {$\Z$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` if you want, in addition to @AlanMunn's comment, to typeset the `pi` as `\pi`.

Comment: Thank you, guys!

Comment: @AlanMunn: There's another thing: when I type pi instead of \pi, the result is pi instead of the symbol of pi. Any clue?

Comment: Yes, see @marmot 's answer. In the coordinates you want the *value* of pi, i.e., 3.14159... which is `pi`. But when you put the node label, TikZ just puts whatever is in the list. It can't know that you want to represent `pi` as `\pi` (which prints the Greek letter).  So you need a separate list for the labels, which is what his answer does.

Comment: Yes @AlanMunn. I investigated the problem in a lot of web sites, even in the Tikz's manual. But always \pi was writen down as \pi. So, your and marmot's explanation were very helpful. I'm new in Latex and I'm just learning. Again, thanks very much!

Comment: Well `\pi` is always just the symbol, not the value. But TikZ allows all sorts of mathematical functions inside coordinates and other calculations, including `pi` and `e`, See §94.3 of the TikZ manual for a complete list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full credit to Alan Munn, whose comment solves the problem, and which is why this is a community wiki. Apart from that I would not use the shifts (and it is better not to use `\x` and `\y` if you consider also loading `calc` and using it). So here I repost my above comment.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-stealth] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
\foreach \X in  {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
{\draw (\X,3pt) -- (\X,-3pt) node[below] {$\X$};}
\foreach \Y/\Z in  {{1/2}/\frac{1}{2},{4/3}/\frac{4}{3},{-2/3}/\frac{-2}{3}, pi/\pi,
e/\mathrm{e}}
{\draw (\Y,-3pt) -- (\Y,3pt) node[above] {$\Z$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked very well! Thank you!

Comment: @Eric You're welcome. I was just spelling out Alan's comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
\draw [->] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
    \foreach \x in  {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)}]   (0,3pt) -- (0,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y [count=\i] in  {1/2,4/3,-2/3, e, pi}
{
\draw[shift={(\y,0)}]   (0,-3pt) -- (0,3pt)
    \ifnum\i=5
node[above] {$\pi$};
    \else
node[above] {\y};
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]