# How to draw the line containig the points origin and $(\sqrt{3},0)$

Tags: line

How to draw a line whose coordinates contain irrational numbers like square root of non perfect suare numbers `$\sqrt{3}$`, `$\pi$`, etc. In tikz environment

Comment: This may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497459/problem-with-foreach-in-tikz

Comment: What about $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Just substitute for the \pi. See the post and change to your case.

Comment: Not happening..what should i write in place  of \pi

Comment: For instance, `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,pi) -- ({sqrt(3)},0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` works. Note that `pi` has no backslash, nor has `sqrt`, and there are braces around `sqrt(3)`.